# SharePoint online Feature Based Development

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

We have a product in SharePoint 2013. This product have several Ribbon buttons which we can Activate Feature based on client demand from Manage Feature page.

Now we are planning to move in SharePoint Online. Is this kind of Feature based development possible in SharePoint Online. Any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online needs to develop add-in instead of farm feature solution, farm feature solution is not supported in SharePoint Online.

Some reference:

[Create a custom ribbon button in the host web of a SharePoint Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-a-custom-ribbon-button-in-the-host-web-of-a-sharepoint-add-in)

[Get started creating SharePoint-hosted SharePoint Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins)